# Master DNS - Windows, Slave DNS - Linux

Tags: windows, dns, bind, oracle-linux

There is a working DNS server in Windows Server 2016. 
I installed and configured slave DNS server in Oracle Linux 7. 
In windows server, I enabled `BIND secondaries`, and `to Listen all ip addresses`.

In Oracle Linux I have these configurations:

named.conf

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { any; };
    allow-transfer { any; };

    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

zone "example.local" IN {
    type slave;
    masters { 10.1.10.2; };
    allow-transfer { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
    file "slaves/example.local";
    allow-update { any; };
};

zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type slave;
    masters { 10.1.10.2; };
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-transfer { any; };
    file "slaves/example.local";
    allow-update { any; };
};



include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

IP address of Windows DNS server: 10.1.10.2 
IP address of Linux slave DNS server: 10.1.10.217 
Hostname of Windows DNS server: dc.example.local 
Hostname of Linux slave DNS server: dc2.example.local

I have not manually created zone files in Linux server. As I read, it takes zone files from Windows. 
But it does not take zone files. 
What may be the reason? 
PC: nslookup dc2.example.local does not return answer.

Comment: Any errors in logs? The DLV has been deprecated and phased out since at least 2015, be wary of following old pages. You also need underscores (_) when dealing with DNS windows zones, needing to use the directive `check-names ignore;`There is also an error in a duplicate `file` directive in your example.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, no error in logs. Ok, I will try with underscores.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, it did not work